# Acer Aspire ES1-512-C32A laptop not powering off with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: power-management, 20.04, shutdown, acer

Just installed latest Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my Acer Aspire ES1-512-C32A laptop and all works great apart from the powering off of the laptop.

When I perform the power off, I need to physically hold down the laptop power button to shutdown the actual laptop. Previously I had Ubuntu 14.04.4 installed and the powering off worked great. There was no need for me to hold down the power button on laptop.

Can anyone pls assist on how to solve this issue with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a Acer Aspire ES1-512-C32A laptop.